# merge multiple objects into multiple array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I'm looking to merge all objects into one big array.
for example 
I have multiple array of objects into one big array

```
    [ 
      [ { slot: 0, time: '08:00' }, { slot: 1, time: '08:10' } ],
      [ { slot: 2, time: '08:20' }, { slot: 3, time: '08:30' } ],
      [ { slot: 4, time: '08:40' }, { slot: 5, time: '08:50' } ],
      [ { slot: 6, time: '09:00' }, { slot: 7, time: '09:10' } ],
      [ { slot: 8, time: '09:20' }, { slot: 9, time: '09:30' } ]
    ]
```

my expected result is

```
 [
    { slot: 0, time: '08:00' },
    { slot: 1, time: '08:10' },
    { slot: 2, time: '08:20' },
    { slot: 3, time: '08:30' },
    { slot: 4, time: '08:40' },
    { slot: 5, time: '08:50' },
    { slot: 6, time: '09:00' },
    { slot: 7, time: '09:10' },
    { slot: 8, time: '09:20' },
    { slot: 9, time: '09:30' }
 ]
```

Comment: is What you want just to flatten the array?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
var data = [ [ { slot: 0, time: '08:00' }, { slot: 1, time: '08:10' } ], [ { slot: 2, time: '08:20' }, { slot: 3, time: '08:30' } ], [ { slot: 4, time: '08:40' }, { slot: 5, time: '08:50' } ], [ { slot: 6, time: '09:00' }, { slot: 7, time: '09:10' } ], [ { slot: 8, time: '09:20' }, { slot: 9, time: '09:30' } ] ],
    result = [].concat(...data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice way! works as I expected! thanks